# django add parents to field

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Product model that has a ManyToMany to Category.

Category has a ForeignKey to itself named parent.

I want to add all parents of selected category to category field.

example for category:

digital appliance->**None** __ Mobile->**digital appliance** __ Samsung->**Mobile** and...

when choose *Samsung* for category of a product, I want to add *Mobile* and *digital appliance* to category

it's my models, the save method doesn't do anything

Class Product:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('s', 'show'),
        ('h', 'hide'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=170, unique=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/products', default='images/no-image-available.png')
    image_list = ImageSpecField(source='thumbnail', processors=[ResizeToFill(400, 200)], format='JPEG',options={'quality': 75})
    image_detail = ImageSpecField(source='thumbnail', processors=[ResizeToFill(1000, 500)], format='JPEG',options={'quality': 100})
    description = models.TextField()
    inventory = models.IntegerField()
    features = models.ManyToManyField(Feature)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='s')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "product"
        verbose_name_plural = "products"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for cat in self.category.all():
            if cat.parent:
                self.category.add(cat.parent)
        return super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    objects = ProductManager()
```

Category and CategoryManager:

```
class CategoryManager(models.Manager):
    def no_parent(self):
        return self.filter(parent=None)

    def get_parent(self, parent):
        return self.filter(parent=parent)


class Category(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', default=None, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,related_name='children')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes more sense to have Foreign Key to category table rather than m2m relation. You can flatten it in the view whenever needed

Comment: with Foreign Key it can have only one category. I know I can show parent categories in template but I want to make it on models.